# Swift enums as index to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

How can I do a simple index into an array using enums in Swift?

I am a C programmer trying to understand Swift. This is perplexing.

```
var  arr: [String] = ["2.16", "4.3", "0.101"]
```

---

```
enum Ptr: Int {
    case first = 0
    case second = 1
    case third = 2    
}
```

---

```
var ix = Int(Ptr.first)
print (ix)
let e = Double (arr[ix])
```

`

I would expect that Ptr.first would yield a 0 integer which I could as an index into array arr.

Comment: `let ix = Ptr.first.rawValue`

Comment: `enum Ptr: Int {
    case first, second, third
}

let  arr = ["2.16", "4.3", "0.101"]
let ix: Ptr = .first
print (ix)

let e = Double(arr[ix.rawValue])`

Comment: Thank you. Coming from decades of C programming, Swift is quite counterintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Why it doesn't work is because all cases in your enum (first, second, third) are essentially of type `Ptr` (the type of your enum). So in order to get 0 you need to access the case's `rawValue` property which is an Int:

```
var ix = Ptr.first.rawValue //accessing the case's rawValue property
print (ix)
let e = Double (arr[ix])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Why couldn't Apple just stick to C?

Comment: Well, swift is a really powerful language. I think you will really like it if you get familiar with the language.